# Programmatically retrieve maximum number of blocks per multiprocessor

Tags: cuda

Is there a way to programmatically retrieve the maximum number of blocks that can fit on a multiprocessor? I understand that if I want to reach the maximum number of blocks per multiprocessor, then I need to figure out how many threads and how much shared memory I can use without constraining the number of blocks. (Oh, and the maximum number of registers)

But, I am looking at

http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_1/rel/toolkit/docs/online/structcudaDeviceProp.html

and I do not see a way to programmatically retrieve the maximum number of blocks per multiprocessor.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know there is no API function to retrieve this number directly.

You could create your own function by retrieving the compute capability major version and using the info in [the programming guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#features-and-technical-specifications). If cc 1.x or 2.x, it's 8 blocks per multiprocessor. If cc 3.x it's 16 blocks per multiprocessor. If cc 5.x [it's 32 blocks](http://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/5-things-you-should-know-about-new-maxwell-gpu-architecture/).

That doesn't future-proof your code, but it may be about the best possible method.